# How to decompress the compressed response In Jmeter Performance Testing tool

Tags: jmeter, compression, zstd

In JMeter Performance Testing tool I get the response in a compressed format so I need to uncompress the entire response using the zStd in the postprocessor.

I have download the jar file zstd-jni-1.5.5-5-win_x86 from the site https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/luben/zstd-jni/1.5.5-5/.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the zstd library to `<Jmeter Installed directory>/libs`

add a post processor -> select language as groovy

```
import com.github.luben.zstd.Zstd

// Get compressed response to variable
def compressedResp = prev.getResponseData();

// Decompress the response using library
def decompressedResp = Zstd.decompress(compressedResp); 
// Setting the decompressed response back 
prev.setResponseData(decompressedResp);
```

> Refer code:
> https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/com.github.luben.zstd.Zstd/decompress?snippet=5ce6b6407e03440004ee29aa

Comment: Thankyou for the response , I tried the above in the JSR223 Postprocessor selecting Language as Groovy but I am getting the below message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.luben.zstd.Zstd
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[?:?]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.lambda$createCallStaticSite$2(CallSiteArray.java:65) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0):

How about just calling [Zstd.decompress()](https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni/blob/v.1.5.5-5/src/main/java/com/github/luben/zstd/Zstd.java#L382) function?

```
def decompressedData = new String(com.github.luben.zstd.Zstd.decompress(prev.getResponseData(), prev.getResponseData().size()))
```

if you want you can store it into a JMeter Variable:

```
vars.put('decompressedData', decompressedData)
```

More information regarding what do these `prev` and `vars` mean: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

When it comes to installing the library:

1. Consider using `win_amd64`, I doubt that you use 32-bit operating system
2. Drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar